# passing a variant to SetSourceData results in "type mismatch"

Tags: excel, charts, type-conversion, type-mismatch, vba

I'm making a pie chart using excel vba, and part of the process requires that I call the function SetSourceData and supply it the "Source" parameter which is supposed to be of type Range. My source parameter happens to be a variant instead, and I get a "Type Mismatch" error. I've seen people pass variants as the source paramater and not get an error. Is there a way around it? Thanks.

Here's some code:

```
mychart.ChartType = xlPie
mychart.SetSourceData Source:=myVariant
```

myVariant contains strings like "Apple", "Banana","Pear"

Comment: Have you tried passing the Variant to a Range variable first and then using that as your source?

Comment: What *exactly* is in myVariant?

Comment: myVariant contains strings, e.g. "Apple", "Banana", "Pear"

Comment: @schmolio007. I'm trying to. Everytime I change something a new error pops up. let me see if i'm able to pass the contents to a range like you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841196(v=office.15).aspx) for documentation on the `Chart.SetSourceData` method. The source MUST be a Range object. So if your variant evaluates to a Range, it's possible that what you are trying to do would work.

But if your variant is an array of Strings or something else (which it sounds from your comments like it might be), then no it won't work.

Declare a variable explicitly typed as a Range, store your data in that variable, and use that in your `Chart.SetSource` method. If you already have your data stored in a variant array, you can do something like the following:

```
Dim wsChartSource as Worksheet
Dim rChartSource as Range

Set wsChartSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet Name")
With wsChartSource
    'Resize Range object to the size of the array
    Set rChartSource = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(UBound(MyVariantArray), UBound(MyVariantArray, 2)))
    'Write array to Range
    rChartSource.Value2 = MyVariantArray
End With

'Now use Range object as source for chart
MyChart.SetSourceData Source:=rChartSource
```